# Optimal estimator of Poisson distribution

Tags: signal-processing, online-resources

As part of my homework, I was asked to solve the following:

> a signal and noise are stochastically independent and it is known that $n\sim Poiss(\mu_n)$ and $x\sim Poiss(\mu_x)$ we define $y=x+n$
>
> 1. Find the optimal estimator(MMSE) of $y$ given $x$.
> 2. Find the linear optimal estimator(MMSE) of $x$ given $y$.

I'm not familiar with optimal estimators, and I couldn't find a good source to study it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since you mention MMSE, perhaps going through the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The MMSE is given by $\widehat{y}=E\left[y\,\middle|~x\right]$ and the equation $y=x+n$ yields $$E\left[y \,\middle|~ x \right] = E\left[x \,\middle|~ x \right]+E\left[n  \,\middle|~ x \right] = x + E[n] = x+\mu_n~,$$
where the second identity holds in view of the independence of $x$ and $n$.

In other words, $\widehat{y}=x+\mu_n$.

(2) The MMSE is given by $\widehat{x}=E\left[ x  \,\middle|~ y \right]$. The relation $y=x+n$ yields $E\left[x  \,\middle|~ y \right] = y-E\left[n  \,\middle|~  y  \right]$. As shown below, we have $E\left[n  \,\middle|~ y  \right] = y\left(\frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n+\mu_x}\right)$.

Therefore, $\widehat{x}=y\left(\frac{\mu_x}{\mu_n+\mu_x}\right)$.

---

We now show that $E\left[n  \,\middle|~ y \right]=y\left(\frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n+\mu_x}\right)$. We have

$$E\left[n  \,\middle|~ y=y' \right]=\sum_{k\leq y'}k\mathbb{P}\left(n=k\left|y=y'\right.\right)~,$$

and therefore

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(n=k  \,\middle|~ 
 y=y' \right) & =\frac{\mathbb{P}\left(n=k,\,y=y'\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(y=y'\right)} \\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}\left(n=k,\,x=y'-k\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(y=y'\right)} \\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}\left(n=k\right)\mathbb{P}\left(x=y'-k\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(y=y'\right)} \\
&= \frac{\left(e^{-\mu_n}\mu_n^k/k!\right)\left(e^{-\mu_x}\mu_x^{y'-k}/(y'-k)!\right)}{\left(e^{-\left(\mu_n+\mu_x\right)}\left(\mu_n+\mu_x\right)^{y'}/y'!\right)}=\left(\begin{array}{c} y' \\ k\end{array}\right) \left(\frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n+\mu_x}\right)^k\left(\frac{\mu_x}{\mu_n+\mu_x}\right)^{y'-k}~,
\end{align}

where the second to last equality above holds since $y\sim {\sf Poisson}(\mu_n+\mu_x)$, which follows from the independence of $x$ and $n$. In other words, for $y'$ fixed,  $\left(\mathbb{P}\left(n=k \,\middle|~y=y' \right)\right)_{k\leq y'}$ is ${\sf Binomial}(y',p)$ with $p= \mu_n \,/(\mu_n+\mu_x)$ and thus

$$E\left[n \,\middle| y=y' \right] = py' = y'\left(\frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n+\mu_x}\right)$$

That is, $E\left[n \,\middle| y \right]=y\left(\frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n+\mu_x}\right)$.

Comment: That is a great answer! thank you so much. If I may, I have another question related(this is where things get tricky!). If $\mu_x=\mu_x(\theta)$, how would you calculate the fisher information of $x$ on $\theta$, $J_x(\theta)$?

Comment: First, let me say that by reading the question again, I realized that this was a homework problem and that you were asking more for hints and references (so I should not have placed a full solution to your question!). Regarding the Fischer information, let us proceed by degrees. You have the expression for the Fischer information given by $\mathcal{J}_{x}(\theta)=E\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f(x;\theta)\right)^2\left|\theta\right.\right]$ where $f$ is the distribution of $x$ with parameter $\theta$. You know that $x$ is Poisson with mean $\mu_x(\theta)$.

Comment: Can you develop the expression above? $x$ is Poisson and hence, $f(x;\theta)=e^{-\mu_x(\theta)}\frac{(\mu_x(\theta))^x}{x!}$. Can you: (i) compute the log of this expression; (ii) compute the derivative with respect to $\theta$ (I am assuming that $\mu_x(\theta)$ is differentiable); (iii) use the property for conditional expectations: $E\left[Xg(Z)\left|Z\right.\right]=g(Z)E[X\left|Z\right.]$ to further simplify the expression. See what is the expression that you get -- it will be given in terms of the derivative of $\mu_x(\theta)$ and $\mu_x(\theta)$ itself. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: while this is true, you did helped me a lot with the homework, and I did learn much for that. I tried myself to solve it for days, so I did not had much choice. thank you again, everything is much clear now :)

Comment: I can't yet give you the bounty, I will give it to you later today.

Comment: I am glad it helped!